# How to run very long ansible tasks?

Tags: ssh, scheduled-tasks, ansible

I have following ansible role tasks: "Task 1", "Task 2", "Task 2.1", "Task 2.2", "Task 3"

I need run them, but all these tasks need a lot of time to complete (from 1 hour to 12 hours) and they must go in special sort order (I mean, that "Task 2.1" must start only after "Task 2" and so on)

How can I do this?

Comment: Use a playbook with those in them in the order needed and /or with some sort of switch statement.

Comment: @linuxdev2013 it's ok, but I need run very long tasks and playbook crashes after running some time.

Answer (score 6):

For a long running task use Ansible's Asynchronous mode to effectively background the task.

```
- name: 'YUM - fire and forget task'
  yum: name=docker-io state=installed
  async: 1000
  poll: 0
  register: yum_sleeper
```

Then follow it up with another task that checks the status of the backgrounded task.

```
- name: 'YUM - check on fire and forget task'
  async_status: jid={{ yum_sleeper.ansible_job_id }}
  register: job_result
  until: job_result.finished
  retries: 30
```

Example taken from Ansible official docs: 
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_async.html